# Decoding JSON string with JS after sending it through python websockets

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, websocket, p5.js

My JavaScript code can't read the values in a JSON object.

My setup is: Sensors on a Raspberry pi -> python -> Websockets <- JS <- p5.js drawing.

I'm not very fluent with JavaScript, so that is where the problem is most likely to be.
Using python, I generate a dictionary which looks like this:

> `a_dict = {'humidity' : 55.1, 'temperature' : 33.9, 'magneticfield' : 13.2}`

I then `json.dumps(a_dict)`, and send it to a server using the [websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html) library.  In the browser, I do:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:1234/")
ws.onmessage = function(event){
    window.sensordata = JSON.parse(event.data);
}
```

Further up that same file, I try to access the data for a `p5.js` drawing:

```
function setup(){ some code here }
function draw() { 
     ellipse(window.sensordata.humidity, 10,10,10)
}
```

This line `window.sensordata.humidity` triggers an

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'humidity' of undefined

Here is what I have tried:

- Changing the order of drawing first / websocket second (and vice versa)
- `console.log(window.sensordata)` prints the correct object with the correct fields, but `console.log(window.sensordata.humidity)` Throws the same error as above.
- Calling it `window.sensordata['humidity']`   also doesn't help.

**Edit:**

- I have tried running it sending just a stream of one string  (instead of a JSON).  That code works (The drawing adapts in real time to the value of the sensor).  This [gist](https://gist.github.com/alphydan/63210b328f87e97e118edb7124322cec) shows the code.
- I have observed a new behavior in the browser console:  if I `console.log(window.sensordata)` inside the draw() function, which runs at about 50fps, the console shows `undefined` for the first 1 to 3 items, and then returns a value after that.  Could it be a delay of the server?

Comment: It's hard to see what the problem is because we can't tell when you are calling `draw()`. `onmessage()` will be asynchronous, so you need to make sure you call `draw()` after the `onmessage()` function is called. This probably means calling `draw()` from within the `onmessage` callback.

Comment: it says `sensordata` is `undefined`, so the question is that `sensordata` wasn't set. I think the problem is that `onmessage` is called after `draw`. Could you call `draw` in `onmessage` and after `sensordata` is set?

Comment: If I try to put `draw()` inside of `onmessage` it doesn't work.  This [gist](https://gist.github.com/alphydan/693fdb5d660ee565209f4319abbc881d) shows that code.  However, if instead of using `json` I use a single string, it does work ([See this Gist which works](https://gist.github.com/alphydan/63210b328f87e97e118edb7124322cec)).  Does this suggest order and nesting are not the cause?

Comment: The only work-around I have found is to  `if (typeof window.sensordata === "undefined"){ hard-code some values } else { pressure = window.sensordata.pressure }`

Comment: As the earlier commenters said, it sounds like there’s a delay before the data is received, so `sensordata` isn’t initially populated. Instead of putting the definition of `draw` in `onmessage`, you need to only _call_ `draw` once `sensordata` has been received.

Comment: @Grilingctus, how do you do that?  The order does not help, so what is the strategy to achieve "call `draw` once `sensordata` has been received"?